# Know when a shelved changelist's content was last modified

Tags: perforce, last-modified, shelve

In our CI flow, we accept a shelved changelist and run the tests against it.
In order to avoid users changing the content of the changelist during the compilation/tests, we duplicate the changelist and run all tests on the copy + submit the copied changelist.
In order to avoid this complicated work, we would like to know if a shelved changelist was modified since the CI was triggered by the time our automation submit it after the tests finish.
We saw that there is a "date" field that should contain the last-modified date but changes in files are not affecting it.
Do you know a good and fast way to check when a shelved changelist was last modified without running complicated diff commands?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you `fstat` the files in the shelved change you can get some stats about them that should be useful, like the md5 checksum and the local modtime.  As long as you can store these somewhere that should be a faster way of validating than re-running all the tests.

Comment: that's partially helps but I guess this is the best I can get.
Thanks for the help!